# rails one to many not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, one-to-many, simple-form

I am relatively new to Rails but I have everything working in the console but for the life of me saving a record through the web page isn't linking the one to many link.

The Models are:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :needs_personals
end

class NeedsPersonal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contact
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact
end
```

I'm using simple_form so the _form.html.erb looks like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @needsPersonal do |f| %>
  <%= f.association :contact %>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And my create method seems pretty standard and looks like this:

```
def create
  @needsPersonal = NeedsPersonal.new(params[:needsPersonal])

  if @needsPersonal.save
    redirect_to @needsPersonal, notice: 'NeedsPersonal was successfully created.'
  else
    render action: "new"
  end
end
```

For some reason this code doesn't assign a contact_id to the table dispite being able to see it being posted.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this naming conventions extracted from http://rails.nuvvo.com/lesson/5017-ruby-coding-convention.

### Classes/Modules

class and module names should be nouns; in mixed case with the first letter of each internal word capitalized.

ex:

```
class Raster,  class Raster::ImageSprite
```

### Methods

Methods should be verbs. All lower case ASCII letters with words separated by underscores ('_')

ex.

```
run(), run_fast(), obj.background_color()
```

### Variables

variable names should be all lower case ASCII letters with words separated by underscore ('_')

ex:

```
i = 1 some_char = SomeChar.new() table_width = 0.0
```

### Constants

constants should be all upper case with words separated by underscores ('_'). ((Huh, is there a reasonable background to distinguish constants from a class name which is a constant at the same time?))

ex:

```
MIN_LENGTH = 1
DEFAULT_HOST = "foo.example.com"
```

### Omission

Speaking of 'Connection Pool' as a variable, you should decide to prefer name by scope such as the following…

'conpool' for local scope (such as local variable)
'@connection_pool' for class scope (such as instance variable)

Comment: Thank you. That link is really useful too.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I solved it. Don't know why I didn't notice this hours ago. The params should be `params[:needs_personal]` and not `params[:needsPersonal]` as above.

Would love to workout the why's and where's of when it is camel case and when underscored.

Comment: Hey Jaijaz. Just a heads up. You added an answer, when you should have assigned the answer above as answered. The answer you added should be a comment underneath the answer left by @Lucca. When your accepted answers rate is low, people are less likely to answer your questions on here.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up I do appreciate the feedback. To explain my action, if you notice the time stamps on my answer and the one provided above, I placed my answer before the one above. The process I followed was, the answer above is a fansatic explanation of why my solution worked but doesn't speak to my question itself. It was for this reason I voted up his answer but didn't mark it as the answer.